# am charts - How to pass static array of values

Tags: amcharts

Is there a way to achieve something as

`"dataProvider":` `<?php json_encode($static_array_1) ?>` in amcharts. I've been struggling to figure this out. Could someone please help me/guide me?

I'm fine with anyway of doing this. Either using dataLoader or any other method please.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginTop":0,
            "marginRight": 80,
            "dataProvider": <?php json_encode($static_array_1) ?>,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "position": "left"
            }],
            "graphs": [{
                "id":"g1",
                "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                "bullet": "round",
                "bulletSize": 8,         
                "lineColor": "#d1655d",
                "lineThickness": 2,
                "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
                "type": "smoothedLine",
                "valueField": "value"
            }],
            "chartScrollbar": {
                "graph":"g1",
                "gridAlpha":0,
                "color":"#888888",
                "scrollbarHeight":55,
                "backgroundAlpha":0,
                "selectedBackgroundAlpha":0.1,
                "selectedBackgroundColor":"#888888",
                "graphFillAlpha":0,
                "autoGridCount":true,
                "selectedGraphFillAlpha":0,
                "graphLineAlpha":0.2,
                "graphLineColor":"#c2c2c2",
                "selectedGraphLineColor":"#888888",
                "selectedGraphLineAlpha":1

            },
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY",
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "valueLineEnabled":true,
                "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
                "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
                "fullWidth":true
            },
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY",
            "categoryField": "year",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "minPeriod": "YYYY",
                "parseDates": true,
                "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
                "minorGridEnabled": true
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        });

        chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
        if(chart.zoomChart){
            chart.zoomChart();
        }

        function zoomChart(){
            chart.zoomToIndexes(Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.4), Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.55));
        }
```

Sample array I have as output from SQL query -

```
Array ( [0] => ['DATE','F_L','J_V','L_U','M_C','T_W','T_C'] [1] => ['2015-7',65,0,0,0,20,10] [2] => ['2015-8',32,0,0,0,26,10] )
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "static array of values". Maybe add a sample of what your data looks like.

Comment: Hello Martyn - I have several SQL queries for each of which I loop through the result set and collect the result into an array in PHP. I was using google charts for charting earlier which required me to pass the array as input. If I'm to rewrite my code to call a data.php type of file which runs SQL & returns me the output, it would be a lot of work. Hence, can I in anyway convert the array I have on hand from the SQL query output to json & feed that json or the array directly to amcharts?

Comment: I bet we can convert your array to the one that will be suitable for amCharts. Can you update your answer with a sample of you array?

Comment: Hello Martyn - Thank you very much. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best handled on server-side. Here's a PHP function that will convert your data into structure, useful for amCharts:

```
function consolidateData( $data ) {

  // init result array
  $result = array();

  // get the first row to be used as field names
  $cols = array_shift( $data );

  // add rows
  foreach( $data as $row ) {
    $newrow = array();
    foreach ( $row as $index => $value ) {

      // pad months with zero if necessary
      if ( $cols[ $index ] == 'DATE' ) {
        $value = preg_replace( '/-([0-9]{1})$/', '-0$1', $value );
      }

      $newrow[ $cols[ $index ] ] = $value;
    }
    $result[] = $newrow;
  }

  return $result;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
"dataProvider": <?php json_encode( consolidateData( $static_array_1 ) ) ?>,
```

It will produce a properly-consolidated JSON data and will even convert your months to double-digits because single-digit months are not supported in amCharts:

```
[ {
    "DATE": "2015-07",
    "F_L": 65,
    "J_V": 0,
    "L_U": 0,
    "M_C": 0,
    "T_W": 20,
    "T_C": 10
}, {
    "DATE": "2015-08",
    "F_L": 32,
    "J_V": 0,
    "L_U": 0,
    "M_C": 0,
    "T_W": 26,
    "T_C": 10
} ]
```

Now, you also need to configure your chart properly:

1) Set [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) to suit your dates:

```
"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM"
```

2) Add graphs for each value you want to plot, using [`valueField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#valueField), such as `"F_L"`, `"J_V"`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this detail example may helpful
http://ertantoker.blogspot.com/2013/02/use-amcharts-with-prime-faces.html

Comment: This does not help with the question in any way.